# How to upload image to Firebase Storage and get the DownloadUrl Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

im trying to make this app to learn the methods to use in Firebase, now, im using Cloud Firestore + Storage, but im getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.)
```

im soo new on firebase so i dont know what to do... also there were a lot of updates and changes and some replies in other posts are deprecated ...

```
  Future<void> uploadPic(File foto) async {
    final Reference postImageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Post Images');
    var timeKey = DateTime.now();

    await postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString() + "jpg").putFile(foto)
    .whenComplete(() async { //IM GETTING THE ERROR HERE

    await postImageRef.getDownloadURL().then((value) { //IM GETTING THE ERROR HERE
        posts.imageUrl = value;
      });
    });
  return posts.imageUrl;
  }
```

and here is the submit of the button "save"

```
  void _submit() async {
    if (!formKey.currentState.validate()) return null;
    formKey.currentState.save();

    uploadPic(foto);
    subirPost(posts);
    print(posts.datetime);
    mostrarToast('Producto guardado');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that you do not wait for the downloaded image link to return to you using this method:

**Note:** If you want to upload and write at the same time, you must wait for the completion of the lifting and then write.

1- First, create an external **file** that contains all the related services in Firebase, let's say its name is **Api**, and add this method in it:

```
static Future<dynamic> postFile(
      {@required File imageFile, @required String folderPath}) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    Reference reference =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(folderPath).child(fileName);

    TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot =await reference.putFile(imageFile);

    print(storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());

    var dowUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();


    return  dowUrl;
  }
```

2- When the image is uploaded, this method will return you the link to download the image in Firebase, store it in the object as described below:

```
 String imgUrl = await Api.postFile(
        imageFile: image,
        folderPath: 'image');

    if (imgUrl != null) {

      posts.imageUrl = imgUrl;

      ///Type here the command that will write to the firestore
    }
```

Comment: hey i answered the thread to write my new code, check it i reply to u there

Answer (score 0):

> Check Out This Working Code
> Need An uuid Package: https://pub.dev/packages?q=uuid

```
File _image;
final pickedFile = await ImagePicker()
    .getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 80);
final String filePath = pickedFile != null ? pickedFile.path : '';
if (filePath.isNotEmpty) {
  _image = File(filePath);
  if (_image != null) {
    if (_image != null) {
      final Reference sref = storageReference
          .child('chat_multimedia/images/')
          .child(uuid.v4());

      final UploadTask storageUploadTask = sref.putFile(
        _image,
        SettableMetadata(
          contentType: mime(basename(_image.path)),
        ),
      );
      if (storageUploadTask.snapshot.state == TaskState.success) {
        final String url = await sref.getDownloadURL();
        print('The download URL is ' + url);
      } else if (storageUploadTask.snapshot.state == TaskState.running) {
        storageUploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
          percentage = 100 *
              (event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() /
                  event.totalBytes.toDouble());
          print('THe percentage ' + percentage.toString());
        });
      } else {
        print('Enter A valid Image');
      }

      await storageUploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
        final String downloadUrl = await sref.getDownloadURL();
      });
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: i answered the thread to write my new code, check it i replied to u there